# How to get value from checkbox checked using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Why my javascript code didn't work? This output value is `NaN`.

for example my checkbox html code like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gejala" class="form-check-input checkbox-1x" id="GJ01" value="1"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="gejala" class="form-check-input checkbox-1x" id="GJ02" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="gejala" class="form-check-input checkbox-1x" id="GJ03" value="1">
<h5 id="probabilitas"></h5>
```

and want show this total value probability with js code like on my comment like this :

```
//----my array RULE--//
let AI = ["GJ01","GJ02","GJ03"];
for (var checkbox of markedCheckbox) {
    if(checkbox.checked){
      if(AI.includes(checkbox.id)){
        console.log("Flu Burung");
        document.getElementById("kesimpulan").hidden=false;
        document.getElementById("PE01").hidden=false;    
        document.getElementById("Solusi01").hidden=false; 

        //myBugs code
        for (var checkbox of markedCheckbox){
          if(AI.includes(checkbox.value)){
            y+=parseInt(checkbox.value);
          }
        }
        probabilitas = document.getElementById("probabilitas");
        probabilitas.innerHTML = (probabilitas.innerHTML.slice(0, -1) + y / 10 ) * 100;
      } else if {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML and also how you arrive at `markedCheckbox`

Answer (score 0):

```
parseFloat(probabilitas.innerHTML.slice(0, -1))
```